# Boto3 Read Kinesis stream from oldest record

Tags: boto3, amazon-kinesis

The boto3 docs mention that

> In the request, you can specify the shard iterator type AT_TIMESTAMP to read records from an arbitrary point in time, TRIM_HORIZON to cause ShardIterator to point to the last untrimmed record in the shard in the system (the oldest data record in the shard), or LATEST so that you always read the most recent data in the shard.

This is in

```
my_shard_id = 'shardId-000000000000'

shard_iterator = kinesis_client.get_shard_iterator(StreamName=my_stream_name,
                                                      ShardId=my_shard_id,
                                                      ShardIteratorType='TRIM_HORIZON')
```

Setting ShardIteratorType='TRIM_HORIZON' should give me a generator starting from the oldest item, which is the basis for my entire usecase i.e. being able to spin up a new consumer and have it process all events from the last 24hrs.

However this isn't working for me, I get empty records

```
{u'Records': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'e705d8f2-dd62-f0d5-b551-4dd5ace4499e', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'e705d8f2-dd62-f0d5-b551-4dd5ace4499e', 'content-length': '284', 'x-amz-id-2': '5bI4T8k4DIpvCsBRUtMw1WFgWqa4tT5X8bUj9mg1NGUFMBZe36iqibCRjDHathIe4j6GbmI6v8A+9d1TiBtbGg7/Sn4GduQPDQ0HVpcP/sM=', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'date': 'Sun, 08 Oct 2017 21:04:39 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}, u'NextShardIterator': u'AAAAAAAAAAH1FwRBEtaHytINAF8WzGDaKRaY5OEKCjFS+mKK5AQFqEf1SPJ8crMIMuBSNFOtfFn3KBT63r5f/bu40OLwhDztEbJgeYjciHVJERpFBDENiWOAZ760flMiZ0mXwCGfFW8cq/8hVC/qiwg1yF96+ujIIAz4vzvK7N944LBB2vH35+8noU/FBK9LCHLOxXxNAQXoOarcEPEU6jt112kOwEyT', u'MillisBehindLatest': 0}
{u'Records': [], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RetryAttempts': 0, 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'RequestId': 'c51c2d88-e979-8b07-9748-b8a598ff324c', 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'c51c2d88-e979-8b07-9748-b8a598ff324c', 'content-length': '284', 'x-amz-id-2': 'BE5rXnfii4ifLDlFuIHQxTBpUvhJ2MJKW92QjzDVFNUD4xRgIgcWhn89dA5EbdPo8HGb5MJDzZ+QfGqB9R4JykZmkvTgb3Fd9y9zaionRBk=', 'server': 'Apache-Coyote/1.1', 'date': 'Sun, 08 Oct 2017 21:04:44 GMT', 'content-type': 'application/x-amz-json-1.1'}}, u'NextShardIterator': u'AAAAAAAAAAEE0Qf0P4bXC7fg7yWj5SejVw9AIyN0iEnHWfj+nN8rIFSPwtDASvHIs+ZPcE2E7EU/gcvLqceWZ+GCptAnc6C3AzwsBK4HamaGCbV7K8l0fTnVMvErzboVGGqtAH4iHrimleGzUgJJ0TYgSDmPvdGDXCP+PRtwTFVGGZxK05jxTHf1qqOm74EfOMe65Bg+10MaNO4IO3NePm5lAy6AbQ/q', u'MillisBehindLatest': 0}
```

However the moment I create a new event it shows up here.

I need for this to show all events that the stream has from the last 24hrs.

Answer (score 0):

TRIM_HORIZON starts reading from the oldest item, however it starts from the position it previously stopped using checkpoints. You can see the checkpoint table in DynamoDB.